# When should I close HTablePool in a MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to use `HTablePool` to reduce HTable instance creation. However I don't know where in my mappers/reducers I should put `HTablePool.close()`.

When the application is running, multiple mappers, reducers are called which can run in multiple machines. For the best performance gain, I think there should be one `HTablePool` for each machine and `close()` invocation should be delayed until the whole application is shutting down. But how can we tell those machines to close their pool?

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a Map/Reduce job, I don't think using `HTablePool` will bring you significant improvement.

What an `HTablePool` brings you is:

- **Thread-safety**: `HTablePool` uses a `SynchronizedMap` for your tables, so in the context of a multi-threaded application this is convenient. However, in the context of a Map/Reduce job, you have multiple nodes and tasks are independent so this doesn't really help you.
- **Pooled objects**: Since it's a pool, this allows you to avoid the need of instantiating your `HTable`s every time. This is a valid statement in case you have for example concurrent requests that access HBase continuously, but not so much for a Map/Reduce job since you're instantiating your tables once per task.

So I guess it really depends on your use case, if you're using a Map/Reduce job as you said, then it's probably not worth going with `HTablePool` since you'll still need to instantiate in the `setup` and close in the `cleanup` methods on every task.

The only use case where I would consider using `HTablePool` would be a high-frequency multi-threaded application with lots of concurrent requests - in this case, using a pool is definitely an appropriate use case.

Comment: It's so sad :-( I should avoid using HTable in MapReduce tasks completely. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Is it possible that HTablePool object will be sent to each node?